# How to display thumbnail image from custom post type in another post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, foreach

I have two custom post types "book" and "author".
I want to display author's thumbnail in book's post card.

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'book',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => $paged,
  );

  $report = new WP_Query($args);
?>
                            
<?php if ( $book->have_posts() ) : while ( $book->have_posts() ) : $book->the_post(); ?>
  <!-- book card -->
  <div>
    <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>">
    <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>

    <-- author thumbnail -->
    <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>">
    <--// author thumbnail -->

  </div>
  <!--// book card -->
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

I think here should be loop inside the loop, but don't understand how to implement it.

Comment: you need to find the author post_id and replace the $post->ID with the author post_id.
what is the relationship between book and author? how you know who is the author of the book?

Comment: ok, but what if I have a lot of books with different authors?

Comment: Then you should probably loop over them in that place. Can’t tell you any more than that at this point, since you have not actually answered the questions you were asked for clarification yet.

Comment: @While1 I made relationship between CPT fields with ACF.

Comment: @CBroe sorry, I'm newbie with wordpress and php. This loop should be around all loop or what?

Comment: No, in the place where you want to output _multiple_ author profile pictures, instead of a single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ACF with `Post Object` field type,
change your `<-- author thumbnail -->` section with the following code

```
<-- author thumbnail -->
<?php if ( $book_author = get_field('book_author') ): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($book_author->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
    <--// author thumbnail -->
```

- don't forget to change the field name `book_author` whit your field name

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php if($avatar = get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('ID')) !== FALSE): ?>
<img src="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" alt="">
<?php else: ?>
<img src="/images/no-image-default.jpg">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I made author by CPT

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it